# WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR after SSD install, SATA to PCIe NVMe

Tags: ssd, bsod, sata, pci-express, dell-inspiron

I have a WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR after I installed a new SSD.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7567. From factory it had a Toshiba M.2 SATA SSD Gen 3x4 2280 128GB as the main hard drive and a 500GB HDD.

I started having these issues after upgrading the SSD to a ADATA M.2 NVMe PCle SSD Gen 4x4 2280 1TB. I can install windows and run it.

I looked for it and it seems I am overcloking the CPU. Is there a way I can tell the CPU not to overclock and work at a “normal” speed. Usually the BSOD happens when I am downloading or installing something, I am still setting up my machine and I am installing the software I will be using.

Comment: Also use the Dell Driver Updater App to update all drivers including BIOS. See if there is a minidump that might help you with the error.  I use Nirsoft Bluescreen View to examine minidumps.

Comment: Overclocking doesn’t happen magically. Your system either came overclocked, you performed the overclock yourself, or it’s not overclocked.  If it came overclocked then the problem is unlikely to be due to the overclock (Dell wouldn’t have sold you an unstable overclock).

Comment: I already updated all, BIOS, windows update, Dell update. If it is not overclock maybe it can be a voltage issue. It happens when the PC tries to install something or when I am downloading a big file.

Comment: It’s not a voltage issue.

Comment: [Suspect it’s a memory issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1354483/how-to-fix-memory-management-and-attempted-write-to-readonly-memory-bsod-on-wind/1354936#1354936)

Comment: I will check it, because I also added RAM some months ago. But I did not have problems until now.

Comment: It was an SSD error. I bought a PCIe NVMe card but the mother board only accepts SATA or PCIe. I am surprised it booted correctly. I just got a SATA SSD, same specs as the factory SSD but 1TB and it runs fine now, no errors or BSOD. I’ll be using some days before closing this issue.